# Error when modifying vector member of another class

Tags: c++, vector

I have two classes and one has to change the value of a vector of the other class.
This is the first one, where the vector X to be changed resides:

**Grid.hpp**

```
class Grid{
  public:
    vector<double> X;
}
```

The other class has a reference to the first class and has a function that should modify X:

**BC.hpp**

```
class BC{

  public:

  Grid &grid;
  BC(Grid grid);
  ~BC(){};
  void add_to_X(int n_values);
}
```

**BC.cpp**

```
BC::BC(Grid grid): grid(grid){}

void BC::add_to_X(int n_values){
  vector<double> new_X;
  for(int i=0; i<n_values; i++){
    new_X.push_back(0.1);
  }
  grid.X = new_X;
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(){
// grid and bc classes initialized above
bc.add_to_X(10);
}
```

When I run the `main.cpp` above I get the error `malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb6294027b0: pointer being freed was not allocated`.
I also tried another solution. I wrote a function into the class `grid` which assigns the new vector to the `X` vector from within the class grid itself, but still I have the same error.
If I comment out the row `grid.X = new_X;` the error disappear.
What is wrong with the code above? What is the right way of coding?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I use a debugger and I edited the post. The row is grid.X = new_X; which is causing problems.

Comment: I'd tentatively suggest that `Grid &grid;` is not achieving what you want it to here so in addition to ComicSansMs's explanation (below), you mighr want to ask yourself why you're using a reference rather than simply holding the `Grid` by value. This is not Java and references are not the same. If it's to avoid duplication or keep ownership outside of `BC` then a smart or shared pointer might be a better option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
BC::BC(Grid grid): grid(grid){}
```

What this does is, it *copies* the argument that you pass to the constructor into a temporary `grid`. You then assign your member variable, a reference, to point to this temporary. However, as soon as the constructor exits, that temporary gets destroyed again, so your reference is left dangling.

So you either have to make it references all the way down:

```
BC::BC(Grid& grid): grid(grid){}
```

and then ensure that the caller keeps the respective `Grid` object alive, or have the `BC` store a copy of the `Grid` instead of just a reference.

As was [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976796/error-when-modifying-vector-member-of-another-class/43976895#comment74983032_43976796), you should use this opportunity to improve your debugging skills. Your dangling reference will be pointing to an invalid object when the crash happens. Dangling references are hard to detect automatically, so it's useful to know what such problems look like in the debugger. See if you can track down what's going wrong by analyzing the problem in the debugger before fixing it.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem! I will use a debugger from now on. Do you have any suggestion about it?

Comment: @MattiaCipriani Whatever fits with your toolchain: Most IDEs (Visual Studio, CLion, XCode, ...) have integrated debugging support and that should be your first choice when using an IDE. Other than that there's gdb for gcc and lldb for clang, which are both pretty powerful, but have a steeper learning curve than the graphical debuggers in IDEs. On Windows there is also WinDbg, which is also very powerful, but probably overkill if all you want to do is debug simple applications.